# what is the use of MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter? and AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter?

Tags: spring

```
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter>
    <beans:property name="messageConverters">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter" />
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

what is the exact meaning of the above code? can anybody explain this.?

Answer (score 0):

AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter is deprecated and is replace by [RequestMappingHandlerAdapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.html)

These classes (as your configuration) are used to extend the HTTP request/response processing. 
The class MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter is a Jackson Json Framework converter which supports Json to Java Bean and vise-a-versa conversion. 
Using this configuration, you don't have to convert Json to Java or Java to json. You can accept Java pojo in your controller method and return Java pojo from controller method. Conversion is handled by spring using mentioned converter class.

This way you can use annotations provided by Jackson on your pojo to control the output